# Easy way to copy code block?

Tags: feature-request, code, user-interface, user-script

Wouldn't it be cool to right click anywhere in a code block and have the option "copy code block to clipboard"?

Comment: How would this even be possible on a web site?

Comment: With firebug on firefox, I can right click on a code block and do "inspect element". This is an element that starts like this: `<pre class="lang-tex prettyprint">` Now if I could strip out all the HTML tags, I would have my code block. This is probably a long way round, but does this not show this is possible?

Comment: For security/privacy reasons, most browsers don't seem to allow javascript to access the clipboard. There are workarounds (see [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)), but they all use flash. On the other hand, javascript run via greasemonkey can access the clipboard.

Comment: Perhaps at least 'select this code block' for copying? This is seen on other sites (for example latex-community.org)

Comment: Yeah. Select the code for copying works just as well, and looks like it might be easier to implement.

Comment: @Seamus: my point is that right-clicking is surely an OS and browser-specific function. I'm not aware of *any* server-side approaches to affect what appears when I right-click on a website. (Could be wrong, though.) A button for selecting code for copying would be okay, though. (Flash can definitely copy text to the clipboard—see GitHub—but I'm not about to suggest it for this site!)

Comment: @Will Oh I see what you mean. Well, right-clicking was an incidental part of the feature I'm really requesting, which is a quick way to highlight/copy a whole code block...

Answer (score 22):

I now programmed this [Greasemonkey script for Firefox](http://www.scharrer-online.de/raw-attachment/wiki/Software/files/select_code.user.js) to add a '*select code*' text below every `pre` tag. If clicked the tag content will be selected and the user can copy it using CTRL+C or similar.

This is not a full solution yet (only work with Firefox) but could be expanded to all browsers and included in the site javascript files.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: *Please* make it work also with Chrome.

Comment: @lockstep: I will have a look on it

Comment: I've linked to this answer on http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/483/control-a-in-a-code-area-selects-more-than-just-the-code/487#487, where a similar question has come up. The script works there (and I suspect on all stackexchange sites) if you use `// @include http://*.stackexchange.com/*`. Maybe you could incorporate that in the version hosted on your server?

Comment: @lockstep: Does it work with the current version of Chrome?

Comment: @lockstep: It works now. But you need tempermonkey user script manager. Refer : [How to make \`select code\` work with google chrome?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3193)

Comment: @MartinScharrer -- this question has been cited in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6183/579 but trying to connect to your link fails.  can you do something about that, please?

Answer (score 5):

I have created another Greasemonkey (Firefox) / Tampermonkey (Chrome) script that use [clipboard.js](https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/).
When you hover a code section (`<pre><code>`) there is a small `</>` sign that appears on the top right corner of the script. You click it and voilà !

[image]

The code is available on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/kpym/30d90be41ab5c248cdf7).

How to use it :

1. Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) / [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=fr) (Chrome) for your browser.
2. Read the code in the Gist *(if you do not understand some code, do not install it)* ! Click on the [raw version of the gist](https://gist.github.com/kpym/30d90be41ab5c248cdf7/raw/Copy%2520code%2520from%2520SX.user.js).
3. Install it.

Edit : I have created a [second version](https://gist.github.com/kpym/30d90be41ab5c248cdf7#file-copy-code-from-sx-v2-user-js). In the first version the button is not visible if the code is scrolled down. In the second version it stays visible ... and it has a different appearance (more `\tex` one ;)).

Comment: Does this work for code indented by 4 spaces as well?

Comment: I think yes : code indented by 4 spaces is wrapped in `<pre><code>`.