# How to make `select code` work with google chrome?

Tags: discussion, user-script, scripts, javascript

I wanted to make a transition from firefox to chrome (on windows). I managed to get all javascript buttons like ctan package and comment block to work with chrome. But....
the life line - `select code` button eluded me. It seems that it doesn't work with chrome. Without this button I can't migrate to chrome ( I am very serious `:-|`).

## References:

1. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/891/11232
2. [Useful StackApps and other User Scripts for TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2475/11232)

## Question:

How to get `select code` button in google chrome?

## Edit:

As per Martin Scharrer's suggestion (below), I installed Tampermonkey and installed the select_code script through Tampermonkey. Then it works.

Comment: What other goodies do you have? I'd love to learn! :)

Comment: @Dror There is this question: [Useful StackApps and other User Scripts for TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2475) nad this: [User script for CTAN Package and TeXDoc.net buttons](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2467)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested it now and it works fine for me.
I installed the current version of Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.52 m) and then the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) extension, which is apperently like Greasemonkey for Firefox. It wasn't possible to install the script directly because of the "security" settings of Chrome.

Comment: It works! Thanks Martin.

Comment: You can install scripts directly by dragging the file (even from the Download Bar) to the Extensions Tab. In this instance the script really does not work although it _is_ installed. What does Tampermonkey change? Anyway, you may add to the answer how to install the script through Tampermonkey, it is not as easy as Drag-and-Drop (I needed to paste the source into the “Edit New Script” window).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I added the steps involved. But I don't know -- What does Tampermonkey change?

Answer (score 4):

I decided to make it somewhat more elaborate:

Steps to be followed:

1. Install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (press <kbd>Add to chrome</kbd>). (Open this link in chrome)
   [image]
2. (Go to [this answer of Martin Scharrer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/891/11232) and/or) select [to install select_code script.](http://www.scharrer-online.de/raw-attachment/wiki/Software/files/select_code.user.js) You will be asked this:

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

And you are done. Now you will get a `select code` button below the code as in:

[image]

Sorry, but I don't know what tampermonkey does so as to make this code work.

Comment: Please feel free to improve.

Comment: I actually didn't got the pop-up in step 2. It directly installed it using tampermonkey and it worked.