# Add button "Select All"

Tags: feature-request, code, user-interface

May be it is not really a big problem, but it would be a nice addition to the site features if there was a button over or after the code to select all the code. I think it is useful more in cases you use a semi-broken mouse (my case) that forgets that a button is clicked and "unselects" a big part of a big code... And I have to go back to start to select again (Don't ask for my mouse brand because some "Bill" will go after me)...

Independent of my specific problem, in big files it is really useful and many communities use such buttons.

Comment: I sure would like such a feature, not depending on the browser.

Comment: @jfbu thanks... I am going to flag the post as duplicate... It makes sense that more people (than just me) are thinking often this request... (I hope that it will added some time as a default ability without extras)

Comment: @koleygr In turn I am flagging my own as duplicate of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/easy-way-to-copy-code-block which was earlier and had gotten an answer. Thanks for reviving the topic!

Answer (score 4):

For firefox there are nice add-ons to add this missing feature

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/codecopy/

  [image]
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-code/

  [image]

With these add-ons every code block has a little button at the top right which copies the whole block to your clipboard.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't knew that and I am going to test it on my linux... But I think it would be nice to don't have to add external tools for a feature that the site could easily offer... I will test soon and sure use it until (if ever) added as a site feature! Thanks again.

Comment: @koleygr totally agree, it would be much better if the site would have this feature.

Answer (score 3):

The [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX) script](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/27724) provides this functionality through a very minimal icon in the top-right corner of a code display:

[image]

I have the script activated via Tampermonkey in Chrome, but it is supported in other browsers as well.

Comment: Thanks @Werner... I didn't knew that.